# Get-ADComputer along with ipv4address from Test-Connection

Tags: powershell

I have a list of ADComputers

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "Foo*"}
```

I want to see the subset of those that are on-network and returning pings right now.

```
$results = @()
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer.Name -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $results += $computer
    }
}
```

however, now I find I want both the ADComputer object and the IPv4Address that came back from `TestConnection`, so I thought I'd filter again and wrap the Computer in a custom hashtable along with the returned IPv4Address.

```
$results2 = @()
foreach ($result in $results) {
    $ipv4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName $result.Name -Count 1 | Select -ExpandProperty IPv4Address
    $results2 += @{Computer=$result; IPv4Address=$ipv4}
}
```

and then get my results with

```
$results2 | Format-Table Computer.Name, IPv4Address
```

However my results are blank

```
Computer.Name IPv4Address
------------- -----------
(many blank rows follow)
```

How could I get the results I expect out of this? Or alternatively: am I barking up the wrong tree and there's an easier way to do this?

Comment: just fyi, if you only want to get the ipaddress somehow, this would already return the correct information: `Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "Foo*"} -Properties Name, IPv4Address`

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? if so, consider accepting one of the answers.

Comment: @SimonS Thanks for the poke! I thought I'd already put this question to bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$results = foreach ($c in $computers)
{
    $ipv4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName $c.name -count 1 | select -expand IPV4Address
    [PSCustomObject]@{ "Computer" = $c.name ; "IPV4" = $($ipv4.IPAddressToString) }
}
```

you got these Empty lines because the `IPV4Address` Property contains multiple properties instead of one string. the `IPAddressToString` Property contains the IPv4Address on it's own

your output will be saved in `$results` if you want them to output directly, just remove the variable in front of `foreach`

I used a `PSCustomObject` for this because I like to name my properties, if you want to change that to a `hashtable`, change the last code line to:

```
[hashtable]@{ $c = $($ipv4.IPAddressToString) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Clear-Host
(Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name | %{
If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 `
    | Select Address,ProtocolAddress,
    @{Name = 'Status';Expression = {'Online'}}
}
Else{$_ | Select @{Name = 'Address';Expression = {$_}},
@{Name = 'ProtocolAddress';Expression = {'NoAddress'}},
@{Name = 'Status';Expression = {'Offline'}}
}} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Results

```
Address  ProtocolAddress Status 
-------  --------------- ------ 
DC01     192.168.0.11    Online 
EX01     192.168.2.12    Online 
...
WS01     NoAddress       Offline
IIS01    192.168.7.11    Online
...
```

Or here is another way to do what you are after

```
Clear-Host
(Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name | %{
If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{Resolve-DnsName -Name $_ -Type A `
| Select Name,IPaddress,@{Name = 'Status';Expression = {'Online'}}}
Else{
Resolve-DnsName -Name $_ -Type A -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
| Select Name,IPaddress,@{Name = 'Status';Expression = {'Offline'}}
}}
```

Results

```
Name                       IPAddress     Status
----                       ---------     ------
DC01.contoso.com     192.168.0.11  Online
EX01.contoso.com     192.168.2.12  Online
...
WS01.contoso.com     192.168.8.30  Offline
IIS01.contoso.com    192.168.7.11  Online
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a PowerShell script for this exact task:

```
$computers = Get-Content "ListOfWrkStns_Jan18.txt"  

foreach ($computer in $computers) {  

    if (test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 2 -Quiet ) {   

        "$computer is up."  

                } else  

                {"$computer is DOWN!"  

                }      

}
```

You'll just need to create a "ListOfWrkStns.txt" (list of workstations) file to feed it the input of all machine names.

Comment: Right, I explained already how I did this previously. My task was another few steps than this, but thank you! (N.B. that `get-adcomputer -Filter {Name -like "Foo*"}` gets me a list analogous to the one you have in "ListOfWrkStns_Jan18.txt")